# Unable to remove duplicates from search results

Tags: ruby

I've got a search method that returns items where the search term is either in the name of the item or in one of the item's tags.  Here's that method:

```
def self.search(search)
    search.blank? ? [] : list = all(:conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search.strip}%"]) 
    list_two = Illustration.tagged_with('%#{search.strip}%', :any => true)
    ary = list + list_two
    return ary.uniq
end
```

I've also tried some variations of `list & list_two` with no luck.

The list being returned has duplicates.  For example, I have 2 items, one named 'Test' and the other 'Test 5'.  'Test 5' has a tag 'test'.  When I search 'test', the resulting array is `['Test', 'Test', 'Test 5']`

Does anybody see what may be the issue here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below:

```
a = ['Test', 'Test', 'Test 5']
p a.uniq!{|i| i.split(" ").first}
# >> ["Test"]
```

Comment: No luck, I'm still getting the same list in my search results.

Comment: what `return ary.uniq` returns, give some samples,to see the nature.

Comment: I had some bad code in my controllers.  I was never actually calling that version of the method.  Your solution was implemented appropriately in the right location.  Thanks.